# How to save a mat file in another directory in matlab

Tags: matlab, save, mkdir

I want to save a matrix (e.g. "PTX_Data_Raw.mat") in another folder (e.g. Temp folder). I have written below code:

```
mkdir('D:\Projects\ProgrammingPart\Method2_FinalApproved\8-congruent','Temp');
filename=('D:\Projects\ProgrammingPart\Method2_FinalApproved\8-congruent\Temp');
save(filename,'PTX_Data_Raw.mat');
```

but it didn't work. Does anybody can help me for solving this problem?
THX

Comment: You're using `save` wrong.  The first parameter is the filename you want to call the MAT file and second parameter and onwards are the variables you want to save.  Do you want to save the **entire** workspace, or just a matrix from the workspace?  If so, what is that matrix called in your workspace?

Comment: @rayryeng, I want to to save just a matrix from the workspace. The matrix name in work space PTX_Data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going with your comments, you are using `save` wrong. The first parameter is the filename you want to call the MAT file and second parameter and onwards are the variables you want to save.

Therefore, you need to make sure `filename` contains the entire filename, including the path followed by the actual name of the MAT file you want.  After, the second parameter is `PTX_Data` - the name of the matrix you want to save.

```
mkdir('D:\Projects\ProgrammingPart\Method2_FinalApproved\8-congruent','Temp');

%// Change
filename=('D:\Projects\ProgrammingPart\Method2_FinalApproved\8-congruent\Temp\PTX_Data_Raw.mat');

save(filename,'PTX_Data'); %// Change
```

Comment: THX this is exactly that I needed